# MFC TVN_ITEMEXPANDING doesn't call the handler function

Tags: mfc, handler

I have a CTreeCtrl and I like to use its TVN_ITEMEXPANDING message, but the handler function never calls.

**CsetkliensDlg.h**

```
afx_msg void OnItemExpanding(NMHDR* pNmhdr,LRESULT *lResult);
```

**CsetkliensDlg.cpp**

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CCsetkliensDlg, CDialogEx)
ON_NOTIFY_REFLECT(TVN_ITEMEXPANDING, &CCsetkliensDlg::OnItemExpanding)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()
```

...

```
void CCsetkliensDlg::OnItemExpanding(NMHDR* pNmhdr,LRESULT *lResult)
{
    AfxMessageBox("almafa");
}
```

The items have childs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to catch a notification in the parent dialog so you should use ON_NOTIFY instead of ON_NOTIFY_REFLECT.

Of course then your message map will be something lik:

ON_NOTIFY( TVN_ITEMEXPANDING,  CTREECTRL_RESOURCES_ID, ONHandlerFunction)

You can use the reflection mechanism but then the handler should be in a CTreeCtrl derived class.